# ¿Como se pasa información de una base de datos a un jtable?

Tags: java, jtable

Necesito saber como pasar información de un resultSet a un jtable. La idea es que cuando yo digite un código en un jtext se realice una consulta y al oprimir enter se muestre en un jtable, y que al oprimir nuevamente enter se muestre la misma información en la siguiente fila. el problema es que oprimo enter y me reemplaza la información en la primera fila.

[image: aqui una imagen ilustrativa]

Comment: hola, tu base de datos en que motor esta?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Por favor revisa [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78)

Answer (score 1):

Lo que entendí es que si colocas un valor en tu JTextField, este seria la condición de búsqueda en tu base de datos, al darle buscar se realiza la consulta y debes hacer lo siguiente:
**1-** Dejar en cero la cantidad de filas de tu JTable: 
**DefaultTableModel modelo=(DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();

modelo.setRowCount(0);**


**2-** Cargar el modelo de tu JTable con lo devuelto en el ResulSet:
**while(resultSet.next()) {

      
modelo.addRow(new Object[ ] {

            
resultSet.getInt("ID"),

            
resultSet.getString("NOMBRE"),

            
resultSet.getString("APELLIDO"),

            
resultSet.getInt("EDAD")

      
});
}**

Claro que los datos del getString o getInt deben ser con las columnas de tu base de datos que vas a recuperar.